# PHP - Check to see existance

Tags: php, email

I am having some difficultly getting this to work.  I want to check to see if a record exists in the memusers table.  If it does send and email.  If it does not, add to a table.  Am I simply overlooking something?  Thanks!

```
    //**********  Check if specific record exists  ************
global $conn;
$strSQLExists = "select * from memusers where Email='".$values["Email"]."'";
$rsExists = db_query($strSQLExists,$conn);
$data=db_fetch_array($rsExists);
if($data)
{

//**********  Send email with new data  ************

$email='".$values["Email"]."';
$from="admin@test.com";
$msg="Welcome!";
$subject="Welcome!";

foreach($values as $field=>$value)
{
    if(!IsBinaryType($pageObject->pSet->getFieldType($field)))
        $msg.= $field." : ".$value."\r\n";
}

$ret=runner_mail(array('to' => $email, 'subject' => $subject, 'body' => $msg, 'from'=>$from));
if(!$ret["mailed"])
    echo $ret["message"];
}
else
{
    $strSQLInsert = "insert into memusers(Email, AccessType) values ('".$values["Email"]."','".$values["Accesstype"]."')";
CustomQuery($strSQLInsert);
}

return true;
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Some reading on SQL injection might be required

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$strSQLExists = "select * from memusers where Email='".$values["Email"]."'";
$rsExists = mysql_query($strSQLExists,$conn);
$data=mysql_fetch_array($rsExists);
$num = mysql_num_rows($data);
if($num == 0)
{
//do something
}
else
{
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$email='".$values["Email"]."';` is wrong code this should be `$email=$values["Email"];`